# Remove does not work as intended for dictionary with nested list

Tags: python, dictionary, nested-lists

I have this dictionary with a `key, value` pair where the `value` is a nested list. Based on the condition if the `key` is not found within a list in `value` object,  I'd like to `remove` it.

What I've done is:

```
for key, value in example.items():
    for val in value:
        if key not in val:
            value.remove(val)
```

What I don't understand is, why has this worked for the first `key, val` pair but not the second? As below...

```
example = {"a": [["a", "b", "c", "d"],
                 ["e", "f", "g", "h"],
                 ["a", "i", "j", "k"],
                 ["f", "y", "a", "q"],
                 ["a", "b", "c", "d"],
                 ["e", "f", "b", "h"],
                 ["a", "i", "j", "k"],
                 ["o", "p", "a", "l"]],
           "b": [["a", "b", "c", "d"],
                 ["e", "f", "b", "h"],
                 ["a", "i", "j", "k"],
                 ["o", "p", "a", "l"],
                 ["a", "b", "c", "d"],
                 ["e", "f", "g", "h"],
                 ["a", "i", "j", "k"],
                 ["f", "y", "a", "q"]]}
```

Using that code block above the output is:

```
{'a': [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'i', 'j', 'k'], ['f', 'y', 'a', 'q'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'i', 'j', 'k'], ['o', 'p', 'a', 'l']], 'b': [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['e', 'f', 'b', 'h'], ['o', 'p', 'a', 'l'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'i', 'j', 'k']]}
```

I've come across this one liner, which seems to work fine (assuming that the index of the specified element is consistent) -

```
for k,v in my_dict.items():
    my_dict[k] = list(filter(lambda x: x[0] == k, v))
```

but why doesn't `remove` work as intended for above example?

Comment: Removing items from a container you're iterating over will likely cause items to be skipped.

Comment: @jasonharper really? why will it cause items to be skipped?

Comment: Because iteration visits the item at index 0, then the item at index 1, then the item at index 2, and so on.  If you remove any items, then later items may move down to an index that has already been visited.

Comment: @jasonharper, ahhh right ok, makes sense. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it does not work even for the first element. The core problem is that you mutate the list you are iterating over, in particular this:

```
    for val in value:
        if key not in val:
            value.remove(val)
```

What happens here, is that internally, the iterator is implemented using indices. What it means show following example:

```
In [36]: lst = [0,1,2,3]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       

In [37]: for item in lst: 
    ...:     lst.remove(item) 
    ...:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       

In [38]: lst                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
Out[38]: [1, 3]
```

Note that at first iteration you are processing 0-th element, and remove that one. At the end of this iteration the internal index gets increased to 1. However by removing the 0-th element, the whole list gets shifted so you actually skip the element '1' which is now at 0-th position. Similar thing happens once again skipping the '3'.

Note that this is behavior of standard python implementation (in general i *think* that the behavior is undefined.

What happens in your case is that in the first case all the elements that followed immediately after the removed element is not evaluated (as in the dummy case above). The only difference between `'a'` and `'b'` lists are that  in case of `'a'` list it just happens that all lists immediately following removed list contains `'a'` anyway so you do not want them removed (i.e., it does not matter that you skipped them during the evaluation.

Easy fix to fix this problem is to create the copy of the list you are iterating over:

```
    for val in list(value):
        if key not in val:
            value.remove(val)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for example and explanation. Still learning Python internals and this makes perfect sense. Thanks to @jasonharper as well